# Native Lazyload plugin installed but not detected by PageSpeed tool

Tags: pagespeed, lazy-loading

I installed the Native Lazyload plugin and immediately my web pages were opening faster on both mobile and desktop.

However when I re-ran the PageSpeeds insight review the report is still suggesting I install a Lazyload plugin.

This recommendation only relates to the mobile view report.

Does this mean that Native Lazyload plugin only works for desktop?

Thanks in advance

Neil

Comment: I got the same question!  Any progress at your end?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question, but think I have found the answer.

The native lazyload has quite limited browser support:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=loading-lazy-attr
On mobile, it's currently only implemented on Android Chrome and the Android Browser.

I assumed at first that it was this lack of browser support which would mean that Page Insights would not flag the native method as valid.

However, expanding the audit on the Page Insights tool linked to this [bug report page](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/6677).  Here someone from Google said they are working on it (this was 9 days ago).

Ultimately, Page Insights suggestions shouldn't be considered as more important than observed speed issues (I could see the lazyloading was working even when Page Insights said it wasn't).  However, I appreciate that clients don't always understand this and just want a high score.